# нужно сократить код с помощью цикла

Tags: python, сортировка, список

Дан массив состоящий из целых чисел. Нужно, чтоб элементы нового массива являлись индексами старого отсортированного массива.

Код уже написан, но не идеальный, как можно его сократить?
Через цикл попробовала, но что-то не получилось.

**upd**: сорри, забыла написать, что если сортировать, то надо обойтись без использования каких-либо функции/методов.

Пример:

```
a = [3, 6, 1, 5] #старый
b = [2, 0, 3, 1] #новый
```

Мой код:

```
n = 8
a = [1, 7, 3, 0, -3, -6, 4, 8]
b = a.copy()
c = []
min1 = min(a)
a.remove(min1)
first = b.index(min1)
c.append(first)
min2 = min(a)
a.remove(min2)
second = b.index(min2)
c.append(second)
min3 = min(a)
a.remove(min3)
third = b.index(min3)
c.append(third)
min4 = min(a)
a.remove(min4)
fourth = b.index(min4)
c.append(fourth)
min5 = min(a)
a.remove(min5)
fifth = b.index(min5)
c.append(fifth)
min6 = min(a)
a.remove(min6)
sixth = b.index(min6)
c.append(sixth)
min7 = min(a)
a.remove(min7)
seventh = b.index(min7)
c.append(seventh)
max = max(a)
eighth = b.index(max)
c.append(eighth)
print(c)
```

Comment: Там сортировка в обратном порядке?

Comment: в порядке возрастания

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно так:

```
a = [3, 6, 1, 5]  # старый
```

Создать словарь индекс:значение

```
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(a)}
>>> my_dict
{0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 1, 3: 5}
```

Новый список со старыми индексами, взятыми из `my_dict`:

```
b = [my_dict[k] for k in sorted(a)]
>>> b
[2, 0, 3, 1]  # новый
```

**UPD** Без `sorted()`:

```
a = [5, -6, 7, -8, 9, 0, 0, 0, -42, 13, -42, -42]
b = []

my_dict = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(a)}
while my_dict:
    current_min = min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
    b.append(current_min)
    my_dict.pop(current_min)
```

в результате в `b` будет:

```
>>> b
[8, 10, 11, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 0, 2, 4, 9]
```

Comment: а без sorted() это не делается?

Comment: просто препод настаивает на этом, и вот я в тупике

Comment: @sunshine Ну, сделайте свою "пузырьковую сортировку" тогда

Comment: @sunshine в "старом" списке могут быть повторяющиеся значения?

Comment: @Jack_oS да могут, в принципе, я этот момент пропустила,  оказывается.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ok, спасибо, что уделили время и внимание, я тогда сама как-нибудь попробую дальше

Comment: @sunshine добавил в ответ без sorted()

Comment: @Jack_oS спасибо, но теперь препод сказал, что вообще не использовать какие-либо функции/методы. большое спасибо✊

Comment: @sunshine ни min, ни enumerate?

Comment: @Jack_oS да, все верно

Answer (score 5):

Ну, например, так:

```
b = [i[1] for i in sorted(zip(a, range(len(a))))]
```

- делаем список кортежей вида `(число, индекс)`
- сортируем эти кортежи (сортировка идёт не только по числу,но и по индексу, но нам это никак не мешает)
- извлекаем индексы из кортежей

Comment: Список кортежей `(индекс, значение)` ещё можно получить через `enumerate(lst)`.

Comment: @Jazzis Можно, но тогда чтобы получить правильную сортировку нужно будет указывать ключ сортировки. Я хотел написать и этот вариант, но он почти такой же будет по сути

Answer (score 3):

Можно через `enumerate` создать последовательность из пар `<индекс>` и `<значение>`, после отсортировать по `<значению>`:

```
a = [1, 7, 3, 0, -3, -6, 4, 8]
b = sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])
print([x[0] for x in b])
```

Результат:

```
[5, 4, 3, 0, 2, 6, 1, 7]
```